# Multilingual Chatbot using Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: azure, botframework, multilingual, chatbot

I have been trying to make Chatbot which reply to user´s language. I have managed to attain it in normal dialogs but i don´t see anyway to make it work in Formflow component such as Prompt Class & Describe class along with Prompt.Confirm()statement. It is really difficult to fing some relevant documents which can guide me through the process.

I am storing the Language code in the Azure table storage so and using Microsoft translater API.

Dialog:

```
            string message = $"Lo siento, no puedo procesar tu peticion: '{result.Query}'.";
        await context.PostAsync(message.ToUserLocale(context));
```

Problem:

```
        [Prompt("¿Para qué fecha quieres reservar la habitación?")]
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
```

Not sure how to implement the same in the prompt part.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you reviewed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-localize ?

Comment: @EricDahlvang yes i did and i managed to use translate in Prompt.Confirm but now i have a major issue. Now bot tries to translate E-mail ID in user´s language and it breaks the following process.